# Android Scale ImageView Within FrameLayout

Tags: image, imageview, scaling

My app requires the imageview scaling ,moving and rotating within the framelayout.All are done successfully but the actions are working within the imageview bounds,not on the framelayout.here is my xml and java :

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/square_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/new_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="matrix"


            />


    </FrameLayout>


   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_img);

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {


    //mScaleFactor gets from scaleGesture
    float scaleImageCenterX = (imageView.getWidth()*mScaleFactor)/2;
    float scaleImageCenterY = (imageView.getHeight()*mScaleFactor)/2;

    mMatrix.reset();
    mMatrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    mMatrix.postRotate(mRotationDegrees,scaleImageCenterX,scaleImageCenterY);
    mMatrix.postTranslate(mFocusX - scaleImageCenterX, mFocusY - scaleImageCenterY);
    // ImageView view = (ImageView)imageView;
    imageView.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);



    return true;


}
```

[image: before scaling imageview]

[image: after scaling imageview]

Only the image is scaling (ImageView not Scaling). Please give the right direction or any suggestion friends.